# Update multiple documents with their corresponding iteration number?

Tags: mongodb, iteration, mongoid

I'm looking for a way to update a collection of documents while using the iteration number/index of the current document being updated in my update clause.

Something in the lines of:

```ruby
Book.collection.find(category: 'Horror').update({ book_index: $current_iteration_index })
```

Is this possible? I couldn't find anything similar.

Thanks!

Comment: As an update operator, there is no such thing. All you can do is "loop" the results and update each document found. Bulk operations are the best option for "bulk" updating.

Comment: @NeilLunn, So that means I'm forced to do 2 roundtrips to the database. One to query, then one to bulk write. Correct? I was trying to avoid doing that...